# Mobile Safari-15 bottom navigation area issue

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, ios15

**Issue**

If you open a modal (position absolute or fixed) when bottom navigation is collapsed, bottom navigation area remains with empty area. I think the area is browser area, so there is no way to get rid of the area by css or javascript.

Is there any way to remove the empty area?

- I set body position to fixed to prevent body scroll. It seems to occur when body position is fixed

[Safari-15 bottom navigation area issue video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xA2q_G3ykX8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same issue.I use bootstrap (4.1v) and set

```
.modal .modal-dialog-centered {
        min-height: 100vh;
}
```

and

```
html,body{
height:100vh;
}
```

Thats fix my issues with modals in IOS.

Comment: Sadly, it is not working for me

Comment: html,body{
height:100vh;
}

.modal-dialog{
min-height: 100vh;
height:100%
}

check if the css styles are not overwritten. If necessary put! important. I am sure you have to use height: 100vh to fix the problem

Comment: Oh with html height 100vh it work!! Thx!

Comment: Could you please tell me why this setting solves the problem?

Comment: The modal doesn't animate accordingly with the Safari bottom bar, so it makes an ugly jump after the bottom bar disappears.